# Unexpected results in Raspberry Pi email notifier

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

Just bought a raspberry pi b+ and decided to tackle some "simple" projects. Currently I'm working trying to sync my gmail account to a LED notifier.

If I have an email, the green LED lights up. If I don't have an email, the red one lights up. The issue is this... as it currently functions, when I have no emails, the green LED lights up, however, when I do have at least 1 email, neither LED lights up. I know everything on the hardware side is working because I've tested different combinations.

I've pasted the code from the [***tutorial***](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-e-mail-notifier-using-leds/python-script) below and from what I can tell it's a very simple conditional with some extra stuff so it can talk to my raspberry pi.

Just seems odd that the `if-statement` always returns true.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, feedparser, time

DEBUG = 1

USERNAME = "my-username"
PASSWORD = "my-password"     

NEWMAIL_OFFSET = 0        # empty inbox
MAIL_CHECK_FREQ = 60      # check mail every 60 seconds

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GREEN_LED = 18
RED_LED = 23
GPIO.setup(GREEN_LED, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(RED_LED, GPIO.OUT)

while True:

    newmails = int(feedparser.parse("https://" + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD +"@mail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom")["feed"]["fullcount"])

    if DEBUG:
            print "You have", newmails, "new emails!"

    if newmails > NEWMAIL_OFFSET:
            GPIO.output(GREEN_LED, True)
            GPIO.output(RED_LED, False)
    else:
            GPIO.output(GREEN_LED, False)
            GPIO.output(RED_LED, True)

    time.sleep(MAIL_CHECK_FREQ)
!
```

Here's my setup...

[image]

[image]

Comment: We don't know how your hardware is connected.

Comment: What's the exclamation mark at the bottom? Did you check you haven't mixed tabs and spaces?

Comment: there aren't any spaces mixed in with the tabs. the exclamation mark is from the tutorial i posted a link to, as far as i can tell it just says it's the end of the file - doesn't even show up when i type in `nano ./filename.py`.

Comment: Just to be clear, can you see the correct number of emails in the debug output ?

Comment: @Himal Yes, the debugger always outputs the correct and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of your hardware picture, it may be that your resistors might be touching there. Also, the lead going to the green LED is not down on an empty row. Currently it would be interacting with pin 16 and your voltage when high is draining to that... This article may help

https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-e-mail-notifier-using-leds/wire-leds

Answer (score 0):

First of all just to make things clear: The code **does not** notify you about new messages as long as there is at least one unread message in your inbox.

The issue with the light is indeed hardware related because I just did the same setup at home and it worked fine. I made some minor changes to the code though:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, feedparser, time, sys

USERNAME = "my-username"
PASSWORD = "my-password"     

NEWMAIL_OFFSET = 0        # empty inbox
MAIL_CHECK_FREQ = 60      # check mail every 60 seconds

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GREEN_LED = 18
RED_LED = 23
GPIO.setup(GREEN_LED, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(RED_LED, GPIO.OUT)

while True:

    try:
        newmails = int(feedparser.parse("https://" + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD +"@mail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom")["feed"]["fullcount"])

        print "You have ", newmails, " unread emails!"

        if newmails > NEWMAIL_OFFSET:
            GPIO.output(GREEN_LED, True)
            GPIO.output(RED_LED, False)
        else:
            GPIO.output(GREEN_LED, False)
            GPIO.output(RED_LED, True)

        time.sleep(MAIL_CHECK_FREQ)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        #Ctrl + C
        #Ensure you are cleaning up the GPIO setup or it might not work correctly after the first run
        GPIO.cleanup()
        break
    except:
        #Here you can capture possible unknown issues with the code
        print("There following error happened: " + str(sys.exc_info()[1]))
    finally:
        pass
```